# Pycharm "Unable to create process using"

Tags: python, pycharm

Last week I tried to run my python file and it work fine but when I tried it today it gave this error:

`Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Programmer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe C:/Users/Programmer/PycharmProjects/help/V1.1.py'`

It also exited with code 101.

I tried updating pip but It didn't do anything.

Comment: Tried it, didn't do anything. I think the problem is Pycharm is having trouble with which Python to use but I only have 3.9 installed.

Comment: I reinstalled python 3.9 and re-added it as my interpreter and its still giving me the same error code.

Comment: Does this interpreter work in the command line? Try installing Python from python.org

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check the interpreter version you're using. If you are using PyCharm, you can choose File -> Settings -> Project: prjectName -> Porject Interpreter. Finally, select the desired Python version number from the Porject Interpreter drop-down menu on the right side of the window.

Answer (score -1):

I know is old, had the same problem, for me it work to run the Pycharm as Administrator.